# 日本語に違和感: 「推奨される編集」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1

(編集しようとしたユーザーとして閲覧しました)

[image: 推奨される編集]

「推奨される編集」が含まれる文言:

> 推奨される編集内容
>
> あなたが推奨した編集は、レビューの承認待ちです。
>
> ento が推奨する編集は、

Answer (score 3):

現在の status を把握しないままずいぶん古いのを掘り起こす感じになってしまいますが，ふつうの suggest のつもりで

> 提案された編集内容

，

> あなたが提案した編集は、レビューの承認待ちです

また

> (user) が提案した編集は

あたりも一案としてどうでしょうか．

Comment: 私も「提案」の方が機能に沿っているなと思います。翻訳チャットルームの関連する発言: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20999/conversation/vs--vs-

Answer (score 1):

> 推奨される編集内容

編集リクエストの内容を確認

> あなたが推奨した編集は、レビューの承認待ちです。

あなたの編集リクエストは、レビューの承認待ちです。

> ento が推奨する編集は、

ento の編集リクエストは、

---

参考: [Qiitaでも「編集リクエスト」という言い方をしています](https://increments.zendesk.com/hc/ja/articles/202374727-%E7%B7%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6) (Qiitaは記事の著作権が執筆者にあるのでちょっと意味合いがずれるかもしれませんが)}